# How do you extend the tablespace when using innodb_file_per_table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

With innodb_file_per_table off, you can create multiple tablespaces on multiple devices if necessary to manage growth, balance I/O, etc.

With the option on, how do you control growth of the files? Do they autoextend? And can you set a maximum and then extend the tablespace for a given table onto another filesystem if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting because last month (July 25, 2012 15 days ago) some asked a similar question about extending the system tablespace file ibdata1 : [Database Design - Creating Multiple databases to avoid the headache of limit on table size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/database-design-creating-multiple-databases-to-avoid-the-headache-of-limit-on/21510#21510)

Please read that link and see if you would like to extend ibdata1 the way I detailed

To be totally honest with you, storing `ibdata` across separate volumes from the [datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is a bad idea , and storing `.ibd` files is even worse, because of

- MetaData Issues : I wrote about this as well

  - `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542) (See WARNING)
  - `Oct 16, 2011` : [Error 'Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'' on query. after restarting mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6859/error-unknown-table-engine-innodb-on-query-after-restarting-mysql/6873#6873)
  - `Sep 28, 2011` : [How to Recover an InnoDB table whose files were moved around](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-to-recover-an-innodb-table-whose-files-were-moved-around/6269#6269)
- Performance Issues : I wrote about that back in August 2011

  - [MySQL InnoDB data file directly on a disk slice (fixed-size)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/mysql-innodb-data-file-directly-on-a-disk-slice-fixed-size/4425#4425)

You will improve things if you go with [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table). Why?

- You only need one `ibdata1` file
- No data would reside in `ibdata1`
- All data and index pages would not spread across multiple tablespaces

Controlling individual tablespace growth is rather simple. You must schedule proper maintenance windows for this:

For example, to shrink an InnoDB table named `mydb.mytable` simply run

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) on, the table shrinks.

With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) off, `ibdata1` just grows rapidly.

There is no autoextend feature for `.ibd` files. That only applies to `ibdata1`. In light of this, the maximum size of an InnoDB table stored in a `.ibd` file would be OS dependent:

- In ext3, an InnoDB table can go to 2TB
- In ext4, an InnoDB table can go to 16TB

To be more blunt, you should never attempt to spread `.ibd` to other volumes. Percona has strongly denounced this : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/25/spreading-ibd-files-across-multiple-disks-the-optimization-that-isnt/