# Configuring MySQL (my.cnf) for MyISAM and InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I want to convert some (not all) the MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

- [Current my.cnf](http://pastebin.com/FW8YXtLQ)
- [Show engines output](http://pastebin.com/tzgMFbmA)
- Server has two 6-core Xeon processors (2 threads per core = 24 threads)

What would be the best configuration? (need to add InnoDB settings, because there are no InnoDB settings in my `my.cnf`).

[image: show engines]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned before you are running

- MySQL 5.5.29
- 16 GB RAM

Here are some good settings to start with

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=2
innodb_read_io_threads=12
innodb_write_io_threads=12
innodb_io_capacity=300
innodb_log_file_size=128M
```

Don't do the conversion yet !!!

Put there settings in my.cnf, then do the following

```
service mysql stop
cd /var/lib/mysql
rm -f ibdata1 ib_logfile*
service mysql start
```

Now, you can do the conversion.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-05-10 10:44 EDT

Here are my past posts on tuning InnoDB for better CPU usage

- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)

Here are my past posts on tuning InnoDB

- `Feb 16, 2011` : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)
- `Apr 14, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Oct 22, 2012` : [How large should be mysql innodb_buffer_pool_size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/27341#27341)

Comment: When I try this I get an error?  I've already done the conversion prior to adjusting the my.cnf.

Comment: Does this work with MariaDb as well?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA If the server has just 2G memory what's your recommendation?

Comment: @MalusJan default values are sufficient when memory is at a premium. The OS needs memory more than the DB when the amount of RAM is low. Personally, I would start with 512M for innodb_buffer_pool_size and tune conservatively from there.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I start working on a web application which is hosted in linux (ubuntu) with 2G RAM and 2 CPU. but the mysqld process get about 70% of the memory and do not release it. There is a backup process (mysqldump) run each midnight which takes lots of memory. I want o know if there is any way to release the memory taken by mysqldump or optimising the mysql.cnf (MySQL 5.7)? I'll put the config file in next comment.
Thanks

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Config file: `[mysql]


[mysqld]
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M



key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M



[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

`