# MySQL57 is using 25% CPU and 10% Memory on Desktop

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I do a simple left join query on two fairly large table using MySQL57. It takes a long time. I check my desktop's CPU and memory usage for MySQL. It only uses 25% CPU and 10% Memory on my Desktop of Intel 4 core 3.5GHz and 12GB ram.

Do you know how to increase the CPU usuage and memory allocation to MySQL?

```
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF ,
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON  ,
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10  ,
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON  ,
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts    8   ,
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000  ,
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5   ,
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF ,
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF ,
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF ,
innodb_api_trx_level    0   ,
innodb_autoextend_increment 64  ,
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1   ,
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   8388608 ,
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON  ,
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF ,
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25  ,
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool  ,
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    1   ,
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF ,
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON  ,
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF ,
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728   ,
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25  ,
innodb_change_buffering all ,
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32   ,
innodb_checksums    ON  ,
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF ,
innodb_commit_concurrency   0   ,
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5   ,
innodb_compression_level    6   ,
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50  ,
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000    ,
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend  ,
innodb_data_home_dir        ,
innodb_default_row_format   dynamic ,
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF ,
innodb_doublewrite  ON  ,
innodb_fast_shutdown    1   ,
innodb_file_format  Barracuda   ,
innodb_file_format_check    ON  ,
innodb_file_format_max  Barracuda   ,
innodb_file_per_table   ON  ,
innodb_fill_factor  100 ,
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1   ,
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1   ,
innodb_flush_method     ,
innodb_flush_neighbors  1   ,
innodb_flush_sync   ON  ,
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30  ,
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF ,
innodb_force_recovery   0   ,
innodb_ft_aux_table     ,
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000 ,
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF ,
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON  ,
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84  ,
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3   ,
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000    ,
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000  ,
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table     ,
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2   ,
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000   ,
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table       ,
innodb_io_capacity  200 ,
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000    ,
innodb_large_prefix ON  ,
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50  ,
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF ,
innodb_log_buffer_size  1048576 ,
innodb_log_checksums    ON  ,
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON  ,
innodb_log_file_size    50331648    ,
innodb_log_files_in_group   2   ,
innodb_log_group_home_dir   .\  ,
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192    ,
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024    ,
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75  ,
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0   ,
innodb_max_purge_lag    0   ,
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0   ,
innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824  ,
innodb_monitor_disable      ,
innodb_monitor_enable       ,
innodb_monitor_reset        ,
innodb_monitor_reset_all        ,
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37  ,
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000    ,
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728   ,
innodb_open_files   300 ,
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF ,
innodb_page_cleaners    1   ,
innodb_page_size    16384   ,
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF ,
innodb_purge_batch_size 300 ,
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    128 ,
innodb_purge_threads    4   ,
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF ,
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56  ,
innodb_read_io_threads  4   ,
innodb_read_only    OFF ,
innodb_replication_delay    0   ,
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF ,
innodb_rollback_segments    128 ,
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576 ,
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6   ,
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON  ,
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal ,
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF ,
innodb_stats_persistent ON  ,
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20  ,
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8   ,
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8   ,
innodb_status_output    OFF ,
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF ,
innodb_strict_mode  ON  ,
innodb_support_xa   ON  ,
innodb_sync_array_size  1   ,
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30  ,
innodb_table_locks  ON  ,
innodb_temp_data_file_path  ibtmp1:12M:autoextend   ,
innodb_thread_concurrency   9   ,
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   0   ,
innodb_tmpdir       ,
innodb_undo_directory   .\  ,
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF ,
innodb_undo_logs    128 ,
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0   ,
innodb_use_native_aio   ON  ,
innodb_version  5.7.12  ,
innodb_write_io_threads 4   ,
```

Comment: It looks like your sql may need to be made more performant.  Are you connecting to a server or are you running the sql from a local machine? Had a similar problem in work with life sized environments.  Some improvements to the SQL and you would not believe it.  Processing time reduced from 10 minutes to 3 minutes.  Could you post a sample of your sql?  Notwithstanding this I know this is a problem with relational databases in terms of scalability which is why organisations have chosen to move to hadoop.  It is one way that we got around the performance issues.

Comment: @Ost - Please learn that relational databases do not have a problem with scalability and recommending hadoop is not helpful to someone who is attempting to get more parallelism from MySQL.  There are many organizations using multi-terabyte SQL based RDBMSs with billions of rows that perform extremely well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core)

Comment: @user2392398 - you may want to look at [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41873/10832).

Comment: Hi Experts, I read that MySQL 5.7 has made improvements on the performance. Rest of the posts I found are versions less than 5.7. I am using local machine, a normal home desktop with intel 4core CPU and 12GB ram.     The query is  "select * from XXX where id = 'Apple' and date=YYYYY";

Comment: I have modified my original posts to show the settings under innoDB. Sorry for the format. As you can see, the innodb_thread_concurrency is already set to 9 cores.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has asked you to provide details of the table/index structures, plus the EXPLAIN plan for the query itself.

Comment: 25% of CPU means that you are using all of 1 of your 4 cores.  That _usually_ means that you have a very inefficient query.  Find that query, show it to us, and provide us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant table(s).  Tuning will not solve the problem.  The solution may be as simple as providing a 'composite' index.

Comment: One _connection_ will use _only one_ core.  That will not change for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Memory use has already been covered by other answers, though while you should probably allocate more I suspect that this is not the issue for that particular query.

With regard to CPU use, 25% of a four core system implies that it is a CPU-bound operation and that it is being run on a single thread: it is running one core at 100%. You probably can't do anything about that as the query stands are IIRC mySQL and its variants are currently unable to use multiple cores for a single query. They will of course use multiple cores for multiple concurrent queries (except where this is blocked by data locking matters) but a single long running query is going to use one core for its duration, in which case other than upgrading the CPU (unlikely to be practical as you'll only get marginal per-core gains unless the current machine is very old) trying to improve the query and/or looking for indexing issues is the only way to proceed.

A common cause of high CPU with little memory or IO use is queries with sub-queries that cause scans over small-ish tables, though there are many other possible causes. To give you help with that we'd need to know details of the query (`EXPLAIN` output, and the query itself) and the table & key/index definitions for the relevant objects.

Answer (score 0):

You've 12G of memory yet your buffer pool size is small. Allocate at least half of that to the buffer pool and see if that helps.

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G

Since you're on 5.7 I'd assume your tables are all InnoDB except for the system tables. If not then covert all tables to Innodb.

With regard to the problematic query, provide the Explain output and the table definition of all involved tables.

Comment: What do you mean by Explain output? Table A is 5G, Table B is small. But I am using Table B to do a left join with Table A. So it takes a long time.                          How do I use other cores?

Comment: @user2392398 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html

Comment: try increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size  as per jerichorivera, it should help you.