# Recovering mysql innodb table from table.ibd backup file

Tags: mysql, innodb, disaster-recovery

Just practising DB disaster recovery. As per our back up policy, we do complete disk image back ups every half an hour (on our slave server).

Now for a scenario, where some how a table has been accidentally dropped, I thought recovery would be as simple as -

- copy .ibd and .frm file from backup to mysql data dir.
- alter table tbl_name import tablespace;

On issuing a select, DB throws an error - table does not exist. I understand this might have something to do with `ib_logfile`?

Any ideas how to go about restoring table in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**InnoDB tables cannot be copied the same way that MyISAM tables can.**

Just copying the `.frm` and `.ibd` files from one location to another is not enoght.

Copying the `.frm` and `.ibd` file of an InnoDB table is only good if and only if you can guarantee that the `tablespace id` of the `.ibd` file matches exactly with the `tablespace id` entry in the `metdata` of the `ibdata1` file.

Have a look at  [**Recovering an InnoDB table from only an .ibd file.**](http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file)

Also have a look at  [**This Detailed explanation**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/4846)  from  [**@RolandoMySQLDBA.**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)

Answer (score 0):

Although there are at least three ways to recover from an .ibd file you should never do that in normal restore, only when backups are not available:

1. Update [SPACE_ID in table.ibd](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)
2. Update [SPACE_ID in ibdata1](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/05/13/connecting-orphaned-ibd-files/)
3. [Fetch records from table.ibd](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:mysql-data-recovery:start)

Instead you should backup InnoDB tables correctly with either tool:

- mysqldump
- [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/)
- [mylvmbackup](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/) (if you have LVM)

**UPDATE**: Data recovery toolkit moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)