# Restroring MYSQL databse from .frm and .ibd files (database does not exist error)

Tags: mysql, wamp

please help ...

I want to restore MYSQL database using .frm and .ibd files (that's all I am having). here is additional information..

I reinstalled same version of WAMP without taking backup of mysql data. Now i am remain with "BIN" directory which contains some .frm and .ibd files. When i opend phpmyadmin i can find  My old database and table names in browser but when I click on it it says "'xyz'table doesn't exist". **But exceptionally one of table is working and displaying it's data**. all my tables were of  innoDB.

Comment: Possible Dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files

Answer (score 0):

Get all .ibd and .frm files into a zip or tar.gz and upload it on https://recovery.twindb.com/ it will recover tables from .ibd files.

```
tar zcf database.tar.gz /path/to/dir_with_ibd_and_frm
```