# Need some clarification of another post's method for restoring database with frm and ibd files

Tags: mysql

I want to ask a question in this one post at [Restoring MySQL Tables from .ibd, .frm and mysqllogbin files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files?rq=1) but unfortunately my reputation isn't at 50 yet, so the system won't let me ask in that post.

So I ask here:

She figured out how to get her database restored through some trial and error. Her step #2 said:

> Go into your command/terminal to open the MySQL utility, mysqlfrm, and
>   use it to find the structure of your table that you need to restore.
>   How I did that, was I cd'ed into the file location of mysqlfrm, then
>   entered "mysqlfrm --server=user:pwd@localhost --port=3307
>   "path_to_.frm_file" > table_name.txt". The .txt file should be saved
>   in the same folder as where your utilities are saved if you didn't
>   specify where you wanted it to go.

My question is this: I assume that I put the path to my frm file in that area she puts "path_to_.frm_file" so I'd do something like this: C:\MySQL_5.6.12\data\wordpress\mysqlfrm  but I'm not understanding the "table_name.txt" part. Will I need to put the name of my table in the "table_name" part and am I correct in understanding that this will create a .txt file with my information and it will be saved where I have mysqlfrm and the other MySQL Utilities?

Other question is: she attempted this using WampServer 2.4 and MySQL 5.6.12 on Windows 2003 Server. I'm doing this in WAMP on MySQL 5.6.12 on a laptop running Windows 8. Is her method okay to do on Windows 8 or am I not in the same ballpark. I'd like to know before I would try her method.

Comment: There is _perhaps_ zero difference between those two OSs (in this situation).

Comment: Well that's good to know. So the OS is probably a moot issue. How about the procedure I highlighted? Is my assessment correct?

Answer (score 1):

`table_name.txt` is just the name of the file you're creating to save the `CREATE` statements in.  By default, it should go into the same folder as the utilities, but if you'd rather it go somewhere else, you can do `path_to_where\you_want_it_saved\table_name.txt` and it should go there instead.