# How to Recover mysql Database From mysql data directory in Xampp

Tags: mysql

I have reinstall Windows on my System.I forget to export databases.Now i have .frm and .ibd files in my xampp folder how can i recover my database From these Files?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is purely admin stuff.

Comment: possible dulicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering mysql database from data folder backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files

Answer (score 1):

[mysqld] 
innodb_file_per_table=1 
innodb_force_recovery=5 
--This will make MySQL skip a lot of checks on your data 
--create a dummy database, with dummy tables that have the same names as the --ones you wish to restore. 
-- stop mysql instance
--copy over your .frm files now
--start mysql
mysql> use recover; 
mysql> flush tables; 
mysql> exit;