# How to restore mysql table from .frm files

Tags: mysql, innodb

so I'm trying to restore my tables with the *.frm files in my mysql folder. I have tried the method in this answer: [Restoring MySQL Tables from .ibd, .frm and mysqllogbin files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files?newreg=c983d8b75a774d6fb40b32eaea2702f7) but I got an error saying `[Errno 13] Permission denied: version check` after running the mysql utilities. I am stuck here, I have tried other options which have failed as well. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Permissions is an OS problem.  The files need to be owned by "mysql".  Were you 'root' when copying the files?  Did you preserve the ownership and permissions during the copy?  What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows, I am root and I didn't copy the files. It got deleted/missing after my laptop recorvered from a crash.