# Is it possible to restore a MySql database only using files from Data directory?

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

I have a mysql installed inside a windows virtual machine. The hard drive was crashed and the system is not able to restore all again. But I can have access to entire c: ROOT. So I went to

```
c:/ProgramData/Mysql/Mysql Server 5.5/data/myDatabaseName
```

There I can see different files like: .frm, .opt, .trg and .trn.
In a regular way, I could run a mysqldump to backup and restore all database from command line, but the system is not able to be restored. So I had to copy all these files and past inside inside the same  directory inside same database in another physical instance.

The issue is some tables are not been recognized by this new instance. So I think copy and past is not enough to restore the database.

What am I missing?

Note: Database has innoDb and Myisam tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InnoDB makes it impossible to just cut and paste a database because each `.ibd` files has tablespace_id that are referenced in the data dictionary within `c:/ProgramData/Mysql/Mysql Server 5.5/data/ibdata1`.

Here is a Pictorial Representation of InnoDB (from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: sx]

You cannot recover just a database. You must restore the entire data folder `c:/ProgramData/Mysql/Mysql Server 5.5/data`. Please see my old post [restore table from .frm and .ibd file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file/16911#16911) on reattaching `.ibd` files to the data dictionary.

If the database folder has no `.ibd` files but only `.frm` files, then all the data are contained within `c:/ProgramData/Mysql/Mysql Server 5.5/data/ibdata1`.

You may have mangled the data dictionary. You have to do a complete restore of your datadir or [mysqldump from an original database, shutdown mysqld, delete all of datadir, restart mysqld, and reload the mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261).

Comment: Hi Ronaldo. Thanks a lot. Your suggestion save my day. Well, what I did I copy all the data file from the restored machine, and pasted to a new machine that had some databases, lite Sakila and etc. I just renamed the data diretory to dataS, so the mysql server could not recognize the data directory and past the new data diretcory with the correct name (data) as mysql server was execting. It seems that worked. Even the password was the same of the old machine. I was not abble to access the mysql client using the password they had before the changes. Continuing in the next post ..

Comment: So, I can not see the databse like sakila, test, ect, (as expected) I can see all recovery databases....  Well. my question is... how sure can I be with this method? That means, only copy  and past the data dirrectory, am I sure that I have recovered all data or there could be another place somewhere that mysql could store data or links or dictionary or relationship between tables? As I told I have innoDb and Myisam tables in all databses.