# Cannot access MySQL database after moving files in data directory

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

I am using Xampp locally and I recently did a computer upgrade where I went from XP to Windows 7 and also got a new drive to install Windows on.

I have all my old Xampp files in: `G:\xampp`
I installed the new Xampp in: `C:\xampp` (which is the directory location they were previously in)

I then copied over everything in  `G:\xampp\mysql\data` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`.

When I view the specific database in SQLYog I can see everything fine apart from one table which says:

> Table 'qotm.wp_36rwq4kcgt_options' doesn't exist

...but when I try and connect to the database via a script I get:

> InnoDB: Cannot open table qotm/wp_36rwq4kcgt_options from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.

I visited that link and the closest thing I could find relevant was the part under **Problem Opening Table**; however I *do not* have any  *#sql-*.ibd* files in that directory, nor any *.ibd* files whatsoever in there.

I then found [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/11205) but it only mentions *.ibd* files which I do not have any of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the problem was because I didn't copy the `ibdata*` file. You may expect this file to be located within the respective database folders just like the other related files, but you would be wrong.

My *ibdata* file was located at `mysql/data/ibdata1`; as soon as I copied that to the new location everything was good again.

Note however I have read of this file being located in different locations, so your mileage may vary.