# Mysql database .frm and .ibd file read to understand

Tags: mysql, database-design, files

I want to read .frm and .ibd files in mysql to understand how mysql database engine store data in files.
Which format those file does have, since when I open those files it show non-human readable characters.

Comment: What have you done already? You could always read the source code - or, if these are the only files you have, Google "restore mysql database from ibdata and .frm files".

Comment: these files are read by MySQL and aren't available in human readable form

Comment: At some level, you just need to know the B+Tree structure that is used -- it is the same for table (data + `PRIMARY KEY`) and each secondary index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to restore table stored in a .frm and a .ibd file?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file)

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Cole in a series of posts explains InnoDB internals and on disk format in particular.
I'd start from https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/02/on-learning-innodb-a-journey-to-the-core/ . Get his tool `innodb_ruby`, it's very helpful in the learning.