# Restoring databases using only .frm, .ibd files

Tags: mysql, restore

Today I had the pleasure of losing all my databases.
Luckily I had the `data` folder still intact and with all `.frm`  and `.ibd` files.
Googling for a few hours I came up with a solution that helped me recreate the `.sql` file, and table structure, and then import the `.ibd` file.

The biggest helper with all of this was `mysqlfrm`, which I found to be discontinued. Not sure I would have been able to do this without it.

This was my process:

Export tables to `.sql` file

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:root@127.0.0.1 ./*.frm  --port 3301 > ./dbtables.sql
```

Get all create table commands for easier discard/import tables.
This was used with the `dbtables.sql` file to get all instances of `create table` so it would be easier to find and replace `ALTER TABLE mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE`/`IMPORT TABLESPACE`.

```
^[CREATETABLE].*+$
```

Discard `.ibd` files command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

After discarding, copy the `.ibd` files from you database folder into the "live" version.

Import `.ibd` files command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_actionscheduler_actions IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Do you know of a modern way to restore a DB using just `.frm`, `.ibd` files?

Google and Stack Overflow mostly point to old ways/tools that don't work anymore.

A solution for any OS would be great as I have access to all so can test them without issues, hopefully.

Comment: Which database system and version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restore table from .frm and .ibd file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file)

Comment: Caution:  Any solution that worked before MySQL 8.0 _may not_ work for 8.0.  This is due to the new "data dictionary" and what it stores on disk in case of disaster.

Comment: Right, there are no `.frm` files in MySQL 8.0, so there's no tool to read them. The recommended solution is to keep current backups of your schema and database (that was a better solution pre-8.0 too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst there *might* be a way to do this, I would not recommend you look to it as any kind of "Recovery" Strategy.

> Do you know of a modern way to restore a DB using just .frm, .ibd files?

No.

> Do you know of a modern way to restore a DB ... ?

Yes.
From the **Backups** that you take *expressly* for this purpose.

Trying to "fix" your database's files after an incident like this is like trying to start your car and drive it away after crashing it into a brick wall at high speed...   sure; it *might* work, if you're very, very [un]lucky, but you have *absolutely no idea* what other dangers might be lurking under the hood.

Get your database back to a Known, Good State (your last backup) and move forward from there.

It's a Truth that is, all too often, learned the Hard Way, but...

> Any Data that you don't have *at least* two copies of is Data that you *don't care* about losing ...

Some even suggest going further than that!  Have a read about the [Three Copies Rule](https://www.mpa.com/blog?p=the-three-copies-rule-why-you-need-two-backups-170503) ...