# ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.tablename' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, table, errors

I have a two databases, when I prompt SHOW DATABASES I can see a list of the databases, including mysql, performance_schema and informations_schema.
I can prompt 'SELECT DATABASE_NAME' on both of them, I can prompt 'SHOW TABLES' on both of them, but when I try to query I get the error mentioned in the title of this question.
I use MySQL 5.7.7, and the InnoDB is set to FILE_PER_TABLE. All files are in the correct folder, including the ibdata1 and both of the log files.

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR Cannot find or open table?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25036/error-cannot-find-or-open-table)

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be able to find the answer in the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should

Seems to have the same issue as you.