# Lost admin user ; Update not allowed on current user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, users, root, database-user

I work on MySQL. For making my database more secure I created new user and than deleted 'root' user which had all privileges. I think I did not give full privileges to new user. That's why it is giving error whenever I try to update a table in database.

```
UPDATE command denied to user 'crm_user'@'localhost' for table
```

In case I lost the superuser (in my case it was root) how can I retrieve or get all privileges to get control on my DB. DB is installed on my VPS so I have full control whatever need to do but I have no idea what to do. Please help. Thanks

Comment: check if it works for you 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/forgot-mysql-root-password-reset-garima-masand

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of the question can help hackers or something.

You can reinstall your MySQL. Before the reinstall, take a backup if you can or copy your data files.

There is an [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-to-recover-an-innodb-table-whose-files-were-moved-around) to how can do you recover your data files. If you want to guarantee your data healthy, you can install new MySQL and try that.

Comment: Thtats what I was going to do but was reluctant thinking is it a right way. But you suggested the same means it is rational way to get it solved